# Clean up customize_changeset in DB

Tags: posts, database, theme-customizer, revisions

Is there something similar to

define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 0 );

for customize_changeset type so they're not collected in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a way to disable `customize_changeset` posts from being created. These `customize_changeset` posts are created with the `auto-draft` status in the same way that a `post` gets created with the `auto-draft` status whenever you click on “Add New” in the admin. Note that because the `auto-draft` status is used, any such posts will get automatically deleted after 1 week. See [`wp_delete_auto_drafts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_auto_drafts/).